# Does gcc search CPATH recursively?

Tags: gcc, include

On a Linux system, does gcc recursively search the path declared in CPATH environment variable, or do I need to specify every Includes sub-directory explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CPATH](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables) specifies the list of directories to search.  The compiler searches exactly those directories, not any sub-directories (so no recursive searching).  That is, given a name from `#include "somedir/header.h"`, it will look in the directories specified via `-I` and `-isystem` and specified via `CPATH` and will add `/somedir/header.h` to each of those entries — and that's all.

This is reasonable.  If it did recursive searching, you'd have to worry about getting the order right for files such as `<time.h>` (because there's also `<sys/time.h>` and it might be found by a recursive search).